# How to detect back button is pressed in the next viewController in a navigationController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

I want to detect if back button is pressed in the next viewController in a navigationController. 
Let's say I have VC_A and VC_B viewControllers in a navigationController. I know how to detect if back button is pressed in a current view controller but I do not know how to detect it in a previous viewController.

Edit:

I go from VC_A to VC_B and when I press back button in VC_B then I want to call a function in VC_A.

Comment: i dont understand. can you explain more? or show some code

Comment: how can you press a button of a controller which is not currently in window??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm suggesting you to do that with Notification Center like AglaiaZ suggested you. But if you're not feeling comfortable with using Notification Center, then try this more basic solution with viewWillAppear delegate method in viewController from which you're tracking are you back from B VC. So, let's go.

Set this variable in your current view controller class where you want to trigger method when the back button is pressed on the specific view controller, let's call that specific view controller B VC.

```
let isFromBViewController = false
```

Then in code block where you're triggering the transition to B VC set this variable to true.

```
func goToBViewController() { // This method is triggering transition from A VC to B VC
isFromBViewController = true }
```

And then in viewWillAppear delegate method check did current VC from which we triggered the transition to B VC have appeard from B VC.

```
override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
super.viewWillAppear(animated)

if isFromBViewController {
    // code for doing something when you got back from B VC

    isFromBViewController = false
}}
```

And that's it.

But, again I'm suggesting you to use the notification center as @AglaiaZ suggested, the tutorial is easy, and with that tutorial I've also learned how to use Notification Center and how to create and use custom notifications.

Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

You could use notification center. This link has a nice tutorial: https://learnappmaking.com/notification-center-how-to-swift/

Answer (score 2):

> I want to detect if back button is pressed in the next viewController in a navigationController.

I'm not sure I understand this exactly, but it really doesn't matter much: in essence, you're talking about some view controller (call it `controllerA`), whose views aren't currently visible, finding out about a change that affects some *other* view controller (`controllerB`). The usual reason for needing such a thing is so that `controllerA` can update some data that it manages.

A better way to handle that is to have both controllers share a common data model. Any application state that's affected by something like a view controller being dismissed is shared data that should be part of the data model. `controllerA` really shouldn't care about whether `controllerB`'s back button was tapped or not... that event is *only* the business of `controllerB` (and arguably the navigation controller that manages it). What `controllerA` *should* care about is updating its own views according to whatever changes happened while it was off screen, and those changes should be recorded in the model by `controllerB` and any other view controllers that might have been active along the way.

Comment: So can i use delegate method when i press back button in controllerB and call a function in ControllerA?

Comment: Delegation is one pattern that people often use, but using a shared data model is arguably better. If both controllers share a model object, then they can both update themselves whenever their own `viewWillAppear` is called, and update the model whenever a change happens, or at least when `viewWillDisappear` is called. That absolves them of the need to talk to each other directly, which makes it easy to change one part of your app without impacting others.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to do something when the back button in the navigation bar at the current view controller is pressed, and the user is going back from the current B view controller to A view controller.

Put this line of code in the view controller in which you want to track when the user has pressed the back button.

```
override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

    if isMovingToParent {
        //your code when back button is pressed
    }
}
```

Comment: Thx for your answer. I have a back button in B view controller and when i press it i want to call a function in A view controller.

Comment: Great, so in that case, B view controller shouldn't do nothing with A view controller. You have 2 easy solutions, check the link from @AglaiaZ about Notification Center, it's not complicated at all. Or just track in view controller A in viewWillAppear delegate method when A VC appeared is it from VC B. I'll post new answer with this other solution.

Comment: It sounds like the second way is what i need. Thx in advance.

Comment: Check my new answer.